# CreateContainerError while creating postgresql in k8s

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to run postgresql db at k8s and there is no errors while creating all from file, but pod at the deployment cant create container.
There is my yaml code:

ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres 
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
  POSTGRES_USER: postgresadmin
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: adminpassword
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.18
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data 
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb 
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

Sevice:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports: 
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres
```

after i'm using:

```
kubectl create -f filename
```

i got :

```
configmap/postgres-config created
persistentvolume/postgres-pv-volume created
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-pv-claim created
deployment.apps/postgres created
service/postgres created
```

But when i'm typing:

```
kubectl get pods
```

There is an error:

```
postgres-78496cc865-85kt7   0/1     CreateContainerError   0          13m
```

[this is PV and PVC, no more space at the question to ad that as a code :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh5lH.png)

Comment: Try describing the pod. This will give you more details

Comment: @BenW I did it and there is nothing at Environment inside container :




    Environment Variables from:postgres-config  
    ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:       <none>

Comment: could this be due to an error in the confiп?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who tried to help me! Problem was at PersistentVolume.spec.hostPath.path. There was an invalid character at the path. I tried to use "./path".

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I'm tried to use "./path" as a spec.hostPath.path in my PersistentVolume, but there was an error that said that "."  is an invalid character. I'm replaced "./path" to full path to my folder and its help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you describe the pod, you'll see the warning message in there,
`Warning  FailedScheduling  45s (x2 over 45s)  default-scheduler  persistentvolumeclaim "postgres-pv-claim" not found`

On a high level, a database instance can run within a Kubernetes container. A database instance stores data in files, and the files are stored in persistent volume claims. A `PersistentVolumeClaim` must be created and made available to a PostgreSQL instance.To create the database instance as a container, you use a deployment configuration. In order to provide an access interface that is independent of the particular container, you create a service that provides access to the database. The service remains unchanged even if a container (or pod) is moved to a different node.

In your case, create a PVC resource and bound it to PV so that will be used by the pod. As currently it does not found that , it went into `pending` state. This can be achieved in multiple ways, you can either use the `hostPath` as the local storage,

```
$ k get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
postgres-795cfcd67b-khfgn   1/1     Running   0          18s
```

Sample `PV` and `PVC` configs as below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nautilus
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/mohan"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

You can check the [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) doc for more details. Also, read more about storage class and [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/) for deploying database applications in Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: i'm already had those files, added them to question.